# Finding components of a preimage

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a degree $d$ morphism of complex projective varieties, and let $V\subset Y$ an irreducible subvariety, $W$ its preimage under $f$.  I want to find all of the components of $W$.

Suppose that I've already found several components, $W_1,\ldots,W_k$, and the components that are known are such that the sum of the degrees of the maps $f|_{W_i}$ adds up to $d$, and I know that there exists at least one component where the map restricts to one that isn't finite.

How can I determine if there are any other components of this nature, that don't contribute to the degree of $f$? And if they exist, is there a good way to identify what they are?

(Note: this is an attempt to redo a question I asked a few days ago and deleted, hopefully, this is better phrased.  Roughly, I'm looking for ways to find all the components of the preimage of a variety through a morphism as described above)

Comment: Are you trying to locate the components of *W* for which the restriction of *f* is not dominant?

Comment: The components are of varying dimension, I'm trying to locate the components of $W$ for which $f$ isn't finite, in particular, a strategy for determining that there are no more.

Comment: I should say, finite onto its image, as the dimensions of the components vary

Comment: I suspect you need to know more about your problem: you could always precompose f with the blow up in *X* of any number of divisors on *W* and the degree would not change, but the number of irreducible components of the new *W* would. For instance, if *X=Y* is a surface and V is a curve, you can replace *id: X-->Y* by the blow up of *r* points on *V* and you would get *r+1* components in the inverse image of *V* in *X*.

Comment: In any case, there is a closed subscheme *Z* in *Y* such that the fiber dimension of *f* above points in *Z* is bigger than zero, and it seems that your assumptions imply that *V* is not contained in *Z*. The components of the intersection of *V* and *Z* that have codimension one in *V* will certainly give rise to components in *W* for which the restriction of *f* is not finite.

Comment: @damiano: So, a few things.  First off, I'm fairly confident that there are no divisors in the preimage I'm looking for, if that helps.  And secondly, if I'm reading you correctly, $V\subset Z$, but the fibers aren't irreducible, instead they're mostly isolated points, but I've found a curve over every point of $V$.

Comment: If you found a curve over every point of *V*, then indeed *V* is contained in *Z*. I am not sure what kind of questions you would know how to answer, in order to find the components: without further info on what the morphism *f* in your question is, there might not be a general strategy. In general terms, you are trying to parameterize the locus where some system of equations admits more solutions than expected: often these loci have a very geometric meaning, but that depends on the problem.